# "As a whole" synonym

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, vocabulary

I want another way to say "as a whole" or "as a group" in the example below:

"However, even though it can distinguish between file-backed and anonymous pages in usage accounting, it is unable to solely limit the amount of file-backed pages because Cgroups limits both file-backed and anoymous pages as a whole."

Basically Cgroups is unable to differentiate file-backed and anonymous pages, and it only "looks" at them as a group, so I want another word that conveys that meaning.

Comment: I don't think we're in Kansas anymore, [in toto](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/in-toto).

Comment: @HotLicks I don;t get it

Comment: https://youtu.be/T23jqjlbylg